# OpenVPN route issue

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have OpenVPN set up on my router (running IPFire) and am able to connect to it from off-site with Tunnelblick on OS X 10.7. Once connected I'm unable to properly access any of the systems behind the router. Here's a relevant portion of how the IPs are currently distributed:

### On-site

- 192.168.1.1 - router
- 192.168.1.115 - OS X server
- 192.168.1.117 - Linux server

### Off-site

- 172.16.1.33 - client computer running OS X

As mentioned before, I can connect via OpenVPN from off-site without issue. I can ping both 192.168.1.1 and (what appears to be) 192.168.1.117, but not 192.168.1.115 (although I can ping it on-site). I discovered that SSH-ing to 192.168.1.117 actually logs me in to the router (which should only live at 192.168.1.1), so I'm a little confused how that's even possible.

Here is my `server.conf` file for OpenVPN:

```
daemon openvpnserver
writepid /var/run/openvpn.pid
#DAN prepare OpenVPN for listening on blue and orange
;local 192.168.1.1
dev tun
tun-mtu 1400
proto udp
port 1194
script-security 3 system
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/ipfire/ovpn/ovpn-leases.db 3600
tls-server
ca /var/ipfire/ovpn/ca/cacert.pem
cert /var/ipfire/ovpn/certs/servercert.pem
key /var/ipfire/ovpn/certs/serverkey.pem
dh /var/ipfire/ovpn/ca/dh1024.pem
server 10.219.213.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
status-version 1
status /var/log/ovpnserver.log 30
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
max-clients 100
tls-verify /var/ipfire/ovpn/verify
crl-verify /var/ipfire/ovpn/crls/cacrl.pem
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
```

Here's my client config:

```
tls-client
client
dev tun
proto udp
tun-mtu 1400
remote [redacted] 1194
pkcs12 [redacted].p12
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
ns-cert-type server
tls-remote [redacted]
```

Running `netstat -nr` on the client yields the following output while connected with OpenVPN:

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            172.16.0.1         UGSc           17        5     en0
10.219.213.1/32    10.219.213.5       UGSc            0        0    tun0
10.219.213.5       10.219.213.6       UH              2        0    tun0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              9    45124     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
172.16             link#4             UCS             3        0     en0
172.16.0.1         98:2c:be:a5:a7:99  UHLWIi         18     1689     en0   1199
172.16.1.33        127.0.0.1          UHS             0        0     lo0
172.16.1.36        0:25:4b:b3:cf:84   UHLWIi          4   695688     en0   1122
172.16.255.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0       38     en0
192.168.1          10.219.213.5       UGSc            0        0    tun0

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
::1                                     link#1                          UHL             lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                     UcI             lo0
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                          UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en0/64                           link#4                          UCI             en0
fe80::21e:c2ff:fe01:6f1b%en0            0:1e:c2:1:6f:1b                 UHLI            lo0
ff01::%lo0/32                           fe80::1%lo0                     UmCI            lo0
ff01::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff02::%lo0/32                           fe80::1%lo0                     UmCI            lo0
ff02::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get everything properly routed from the client to the on-site network?

Answer (score 1):

Your config looks fine:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
...
192.168.1          10.219.213.5       UGSc            0        0    tun0
```

Make sure that you've enabled IP forwarding. I'm not familiar with IPFire, but since it's based on Linux, use this command:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: Thanks quanta, I'd seen that mentioned in a few other questions similar to mine. Unfortunately `ip_forward` was already set to 1.

Comment: Besides the .115 and .117, can you ping the other machine behind the OpenVPN server? What happens if you `traceoute -T 192.168.1.115`? Please post the routing table on 192.168.1.115?